# JavaScript - How to differentiate between refreshing/reloading the page and close/unload the page events?

Tags: javascript, tabs

In may chat application I want to differentiate between closing tabs and refreshing them , if the user registers to the chat in one tab then when he opens other tabs he will also be registered ,when there is more than one tab open and the user closes one he will also be still registered. The problem I'm facing is that when there is only one tab opened ,when he refreshes the page he loges out, but I want him to stay logged in.

`client.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var b = localStorage.getItem("localStor");
    if (b === null || b === "{}") {
        console.log("is null");
        localStorage.setItem("localStor", "{}");
    } else {
        console.log("exists");
        var r= JSON.parse(b).cnt + 1;
        var updatedLocal={
            msg: "" , 
            details: {
                name : JSON.parse(b).name,
                email : JSON.parse(b).email
            }, 
            cnt : r
        }
        localStorage.setItem("localStor" , JSON.stringify(updatedLocal));
        console.log("after : " + JSON.parse(localStorage.localStor).cnt);
        //display view for registered user
    }
}, false);



window.addEventListener('unload', function(){
    var b=JSON.parse(localStorage.localStor);
    if (b.cnt === 1) {
        localStorage.removeItem("localStor");
        localStorage.clear();
        navigator.sendBeacon("/log", { email: b.email });
    } else {
        var updatedLocal={
            msg: "" , 
            details: {
                name : b.name,
                email : b.email
            }, 
            cnt : b.cnt - 1
        }
        localStorage.setItem("localStor" , JSON.stringify(updatedLocal));
}, false);
```

The whole idea is that I set a `counter` for the tabs the user opens,so when he opens one more tab I increment the counter ,and when he close a tab I decrement it. Logging out the user when refreshing the last tab is caused by the unload window event because then the counter indeed equals to 1 . I read about the event onbeforeunload but I don't think it may help because in all cases unload code will done when refreshing. How can I know if the user closes or refreshing the tab (in `Javascript` without JQuery)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever heard of cookie?

Comment: yes ,but i'm not allowed to use it

Comment: How your app magically knows user actions with tabs? Sending request?

Comment: @Xlee I create a counter and when new tab is opened then +1 if a tab closed then -1 , that is done in the window events load and unload

Comment: It's interesting invention. But given u can use localStorage,  why not use it to store user info?

Comment: @Xlee I do use it, see the setiem above

Comment: @Xlee and only one local storgae key is allowed ..

Comment: What u use client sever connection, socketio? Web socket?

Comment: I use long polling

Comment: Why not use user uuid as ur key?

Comment: @Xlee how can this help?

Comment: Append it as request parameter/ body across Ajax calls

Comment: If u have a server controls the expiration of user session

Comment: I don't use sessions I use local storage only

Comment: Fine, what's ur server?

Comment: @Xlee I use node.js